# Change background of boxes in baposter

Tags: baposter

I'm not able to change colours of background in boxes in my baposter:

```
\documentclass[a0paper, portrait, margin = 2.2em]{baposter}

\usepackage{url}            % For \url
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\graphicspath{{pix/}}   % Root directory of the pictures 

\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{255, 255, 250}
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{230, 184, 0}
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{255, 255, 250}
\definecolor{backgroundcol}{RGB}{255, 255, 250}
\definecolor{higlightcol}{RGB}{255, 110, 0}

\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{1.5em}#1}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
%\patchcmd{<command>}{<code to replace>}{<code>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}{0em}{0.5\boxwidth}{}{}
\patchcmd{\baposter@box@headerdrawtext@rectangle}{west}{center}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{poster}{
    borderColor=bordercol,
    headerColorOne=headercol1,
    headerColorTwo=headercol1,
    headerFontColor=headerfontcol,
    boxColorOne=boxcolor,
    boxColorTwo=boxcolor,
    headershape=rectangle,
    headerborder=closed,
    headerfont=\Large\scshape,
    textborder=faded,
    headerheight=0.09\textheight,
    colspacing=0.35em, % Column spacing
    bgColorOne=backgroundcol,
    bgColorTwo=backgroundcol
}
%%% Eye Cacther %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{
    Eye Catcher, empty if option eyecatcher=false - unused
}
%%% Title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\sf\scshape
    Changing background of boxes in baposter
}
%%% Authors %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{
    Box Expert
}


\headerbox{Standard box}{name = box1, column = 0, row = 0}{
This is standard box.
}

\headerbox{Highlighted box}{name = box2, column = 0, below = box1,
boxColorOne = purple!40, headerColorOne = purple, headerColorTwo = purple}{
This should be highlighted box.
}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

Whatever I try, background of boxes is the same as background of the poster (I know, in the example they are defined the same). This is not even possible localy, i.e. changing settings in `\headerbox` in box2.

I also try to replace `\headerbox` by `\posterbox` but the situation is the same.

Any suggestions about what may be wrong are warmly welcomed!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason is quite simple - it was caused by
`textborder=faded,`
with
`textborder=rectangle,`
works everything smoothly.

Hope this will help others.