# How to remove background shade of boxes for baposter

Tags: color, tikz-styles, backgrounds, posters, baposter

Here I have a small example of the poster template I am using

```
\documentclass[a0paper,landscape,final]{baposter}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{pgfbaselayers}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\usepackage{helvet}
%\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{palatino}

\newcommand{\captionfont}{\footnotesize}

\selectcolormodel{cmyk}

\graphicspath{{images/}}


\newcommand{\Matrix}[1]{\begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\Vector}[1]{\Matrix{#1}}
\newcommand*{\SET}[1]  {\ensuremath{\mathcal{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\MAT}[1]  {\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\VEC}[1]  {\ensuremath{\bm{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\CONST}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathit{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\norm}[1]{\mathopen\| #1 \mathclose\|}% use instead of $\|x\|$
\newcommand*{\abs}[1]{\mathopen| #1 \mathclose|}% use instead of $\|x\|$
\newcommand*{\absLR}[1]{\left| #1 \right|}% use instead of $\|x\|$

\def\norm#1{\mathopen\| #1 \mathclose\|}% use instead of $\|x\|$
\newcommand{\normLR}[1]{\left\| #1 \right\|}% use instead of $\|x\|$


\setlength{\columnsep}{0.7em}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}



\newcommand{\compresslist}{%
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}%
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
}




\begin{document}


\typeout{Poster Starts}
\background{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \draw (current page.north west)+(-2em,-0em) node[anchor=north west] {\hspace{-2em}\includegraphics[height=1.1\textheight]{silhouettes_background}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\definecolor{silver}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.3}
\definecolor{yellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.9,0.0}
\definecolor{reddishyellow}{cmyk}{0,0.22,1.0,0.0}
\definecolor{black}{cmyk}{0,0,0.0,1.0}
\definecolor{darkYellow}{cmyk}{0,0,1.0,0.5}
\definecolor{darkSilver}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.1}

\definecolor{lightyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.3,0.0}
\definecolor{lighteryellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0.0}
\definecolor{lighteryellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.1,0.0}
\definecolor{lightestyellow}{cmyk}{0,0,0.05,0.0}
\begin{poster}{
  % Show grid to help with alignment
  grid=false,
  % Column spacing
  colspacing=1em,
  % Color style
  bgColorOne=lighteryellow,
  bgColorTwo=lightestyellow,
  borderColor=reddishyellow,
  headerColorOne=yellow,
  headerColorTwo=reddishyellow,
  headerFontColor=black,
  boxColorOne=lightyellow,
  boxColorTwo=lighteryellow,
  % Format of textbox
  textborder=roundedleft,
  % Format of text header
  eyecatcher=false,
  headerborder=open,
  headerheight=0.08\textheight,
  headershape=roundedright,
  headershade=plain,
  headerfont=\Large\textsf, %Sans Serif
  boxshade=plain,
%  background=shade-tb,
  background=plain,
  linewidth=2pt
  }
  % Eye Catcher
  {} % No eye catcher for this poster. If an eye catcher is present, the title is centered between eye-catcher and logo.
  % Title
  {\sf %Sans Serif
  %\bf% Serif
  Expression Invariant Face Recognition using a 3D Morphable Model}
  % Authors
  {\sf %Sans Serif
  % Serif
  Brian Amberg\hspace{3em}
  brian.amberg@unibas.ch\hspace{3em}
  University of Basel, Switzerland
  }
  % University logo
  {{\begin{minipage}{16em}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[height=2em]{msrlogo}
    \includegraphics[height=5.5em]{logo}
  \end{minipage}}
  }

  \tikzstyle{light shaded}=[top color=baposterBGtwo!30!white,bottom color=baposterBGone!30!white,shading=axis,shading angle=30]

  % Width of left inset image
     \newlength{\leftimgwidth}
     \setlength{\leftimgwidth}{0.78em+8.0em}


    \newcommand{\colouredcircle}[1]{%
      \tikz{\useasboundingbox (-0.2em,-0.32em) rectangle(0.2em,0.32em); \draw[draw=black,fill=baposterBGone!80!black!#1!white,line width=0.03em] (0,0) circle(0.18em);}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \headerbox{Contribution}{name=contribution,column=0,row=0,span=4}{
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   {}We introduce a method for expression invariant face recognition. A
   generative 3D Morphable Model (3DMM) is used to separate identity and
   expression components. The expression removal results in greatly increased
   recognition performance, even on difficult datasets, without a decrease in
   performance on expression-less datasets.

   It is applicable to any kind of input data, and was evaluated here on
   textureless range scans.
 }


\end{poster}%
%
\end{document}
```

And I want to remove the background colour, which is like a yellowish colour, for my box titled Contribution.

I have read this thread [Change background of boxes in baposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380318/change-background-of-boxes-in-baposter) but I don't think it's applicable for me as I can't see anything called 'textborder'

Sorry if this is a stupid question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`baposter`](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/baposter/baposter_guide.pdf) documentation:

[image]

As you can read, `plain` mode uses `bgColorOne` which you have defined as `bgColorOne=lighteryellow`. Change it to `white` and the shadow will disappear.
Or change background style from `plain` to `none`.

[image]

**Update: Changing text background**

I cannot find in documentation, but from `baposter.cls`, the background of text in `baposter` boxes is defined with `boxColorOne` and `boxColorTwo`. Therefore, change these parameter in `poster` header or in second parameter of a `headerbox` (see below) to obtain the desired result:

```
\headerbox{Contribution}{name=contribution2, 
         column=0, row=0, span=4, 
         boxColorOne=green!30 %<--------------
  }{
```

[image]

*Side note:*

If you are starting with `baposter`, may be you want to give a try to [`poster`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox-example-poster.pdf) library (from [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox)) which uses similar positioning system as `baposter`, it's a little better documented and offers some other options as flowing text from one box to another. This is a nice [tutorial](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox-tutorial-poster.pdf) and here [one example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378438/1952)

Comment: I want to change the colour inside the text box. That orange/yellow colour with the black text over it. Not the full background

Comment: @Gragbow    I've not well understood. To change text in boxes background play with `boxColorOne` and `boxColorTwo`.

Comment: @Gragbow Please, look at my updated answer.